# Compare and Sort String in array list

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort string array based on on input string , for example thin we have these text

```
"united state"
"sample united"
"united kingdom"
"greece"
"uzbakestan"
```

so when user entered `united` , output will be :

```
"united state"
"united kingdom"
"sample united"
"greece"
"uzbakestan"
```

it shows `united` at first and sort them.

Comment: the example is not ordered in any way I recognize. What are your sorting criteria?

Comment: none of the examples above is sorted unless my alphabet sequence is ditched since the beginning.

Comment: I think he want to altered the sorted result if user provide a keyword. So if user provided united, the result should be altered in a way that strings with united should be at the top of the result and so on.

Comment: Sort by size of empire? Unemployment figures?

Comment: @Jasonw : yes exactly . how can I do this ?

Comment: what is your exact need? what type of sort you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure I entirely understand what you are after - but if you want to print the strings that are "most similar" to your input string first:

You might want to create a [`Comparator<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that will compare between 2 strings according to their [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) from a 3rd string [your input String].

Using this comparator - you can sort your array using [`Arrays.sort(myArray,new MyCustomComparator(inputString))`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

If this is an `ArrayList` like the title suggest [conflicting title and question body] - you can use [`Collections.sort(myList,new MyCustomComparator(inputString))`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: I have made this ,but I can not make constructor to add SortString Value

Comment: Comparator<command> myCommandComprator = new Comparator<InternalDataManager.command>() {

  public int compare(command lhs, command rhs) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return 0;
  }
 };

Comment: @Ata: If you use anonymous inner class - you might want to delcare your `inputString` as a `final` variable [in the method that creates the custom comparator] - and just access it where you need it [you will not need to pass it to the constructor]. I would have created a new [not anonymous] class - but it will obviously work with your approach as well - just declare `inputString` as final in your method, and access it directly.

Answer (score 1):

use this `Collections.sort(your_arraylist_obj);`

Comment: He doesn't want natural order sorting, a custom Comparator should be used here.

Comment: @amit : yes m I need cutom comparator

Answer (score 1):

if you use ArrayList you have to use **Collection** to the sort the array list.

For example:

```
Collections.sort(arrayList);
```

To view:

```
    Iterator<String> i = a.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
```

Comment: He doesn't want natural order sorting, a custom Comparator should be used here.

Comment: please use comparator for your custom sort and use str_array.sort()

Answer (score 0):

I think, first you are listing all the items which contains input keyword. Then adding other items to the list.

```
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {
   //splitting item by space to match with the inputText
   String[] myString = mylist.get(i);
   for(int j=0;j<myString.length;j++) {
      if(myString[j].equals(inputText)) {
        myNewList.add(mylist.get(i));
        break;
      }

    }
```

}

```
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {
   if(!mynewList.contains(mylist.get(i))) {
     myNewList.add(mylist.get(i));
   }

 }
```

might be there is some easy way to do this. But i hope this will give you the output what u r looking for.

First it will add all the strings which contains the input text to the new list, then adding remaining strings.